# NaN values in product id

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Am concatenating my two dataframes base_df and base_df1 with base_df having product id and base_df1 as sales, profit and discount.

```
base_df1
    sales       profit      discount
0   0.050090    0.000000    0.262335
1   0.110793    0.000000    0.260662
2   0.309561    0.864121    0.241432
3   0.039217    0.591474    0.260687
4   0.070205    0.000000    0.263628
```

base_df['Product ID']

```
0    FUR-ADV-10000002
1    FUR-ADV-10000108
2    FUR-ADV-10000183
3    FUR-ADV-10000188
4    FUR-ADV-10000190

final_df=pd.concat([base_df1,base_df], axis=0, ignore_index=True,sort=False)
```

But my `final_df.head()` having NaN values in product_id column, what might be the issue.

```
   sales       Discount    profit     product id
0   0.050090    0.000000    0.262335    NaN
1   0.110793    0.000000    0.260662    NaN
2   0.309561    0.864121    0.241432    NaN
3   0.039217    0.591474    0.260687    NaN
4   0.070205    0.000000    0.263628    NaN
```

Comment: Please show the two input dataframes so that someone might be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: add data into question, not in comments

Answer (score 0):

Try using `axis=1`:

```
final_df=pd.concat([base_df1,base_df], axis=1, sort=False)
```

Output:

```
      sales    profit  discount         ProductID
0  0.050090  0.000000  0.262335  FUR-ADV-10000002
1  0.110793  0.000000  0.260662  FUR-ADV-10000108
2  0.309561  0.864121  0.241432  FUR-ADV-10000183
3  0.039217  0.591474  0.260687  FUR-ADV-10000188
4  0.070205  0.000000  0.263628  FUR-ADV-10000190
```

With `axis=0` you are stacking the dataframes vertically and with pandas using intrinsic data alignment, meaning aligning the data with the indexes, you are generating the following dataframe:

```
final_df=pd.concat([base_df1,base_df], axis=0, sort=False)

      sales    profit  discount         ProductID
0  0.050090  0.000000  0.262335               NaN
1  0.110793  0.000000  0.260662               NaN
2  0.309561  0.864121  0.241432               NaN
3  0.039217  0.591474  0.260687               NaN
4  0.070205  0.000000  0.263628               NaN
0       NaN       NaN       NaN  FUR-ADV-10000002
1       NaN       NaN       NaN  FUR-ADV-10000108
2       NaN       NaN       NaN  FUR-ADV-10000183
3       NaN       NaN       NaN  FUR-ADV-10000188
4       NaN       NaN       NaN  FUR-ADV-10000190
```